# Enumerating a n-item combination of set Java/Groovy

Tags: java, recursion, groovy

I'm trying to write an operation that can enumerate all the combinations of a set of N elements. In other words, the N is unknown and depends on user input. On receiving the N, the function should be able to give all the possible combination of an N-item set, with all elements from a set U. Say, U={A,B,C...J}, 10 elements in total.
One more example of what I need, the function enumerate(3) should tell me all the possible combinations like {A,B,C},{A,D,J} etc., using elements picked from U.

I tried to do this in a way using for loops(initializing an integer since the size of U happen to be 10 in this case, so I can use 123 to denote {A,B,C}...). But the code smells bad and I'd like to know how this can be done in a more elegant with using recursive calls.

Java/Groovy are both acceptable (because I'm trying in them too). If anybody could provide ideas how to do this with closures in Groovy it'll be even more appreciated.

Also please don't use integers to denote the combination as I did, because I think this only applies to a certain U with no generality.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your code attempt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have the solution.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Generator<T> {
    Set<T> source;
    Set<Set<T>> combinations;

    public Generator(Set<T> source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Set<String> source = new HashSet<>();
        for (char character = 'A'; character <= 'Z'; character++){
            source.add(String.valueOf(character));
        }

        final Generator<String> stringGenerator = new Generator<>(source);
        stringGenerator.generate(3);
    }

    public void generate(int size){
        if (size == 0){
            return;
        }
        Set<Set<T>> newCombinations = new HashSet<>();
        for (T element : source) {
            if (combinations == null || combinations.isEmpty()){
                final HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<>();
                set.add(element);
                newCombinations.add(set);
            } else {
                for (Set<T> combination : combinations) {
                    final HashSet<T> newCombination = new HashSet<>(combination);
                    if (newCombination.add(element)) {
                        newCombinations.add(newCombination);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        combinations = newCombinations;
        generate(size - 1);
    }
}
```

It was fast dirty implementation, so probably it misses some cases, but it generally demonstrates the idea with at least one working case.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yurii it works pretty well. I suggest maybe changing generate(int size) to generate(int remainingSize) can better clarify itself?

Comment: @OrlandoL sure, my code needs refactoring. I just outlined the idea. BTW, could you please accept the answer I made?

Comment: Sure @Yurii. The answer is quite generic and flexible, much more than what I expected. Much appreciated